# Installing NVIDIA binaries. Hardware is probably not detected

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gpu-driver

I tried installing the NVIDIA binaries following the procedure given at http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/01/install-nvidia-346-35-ubuntu-1404/ on a UBUNTU 14.10 with a NVIDIA Geforce 630M, but I am running into the following error message at the prompt. "You do not appear to have an nvidia gpu supported by the 346.35..." 
My GPU is in fact being detected. The following is the output from

```
>lspci | less
...
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 630M] (rev ff)
...
```

While it allows me to continue further, I am not sure if I should do it. Is this message expected or should I be checking something else?

Comment: That line just comes from the HWDB. It's matched based on the PCI ID the system can see, nothing to do with the drivers in use.

Comment: the last entry in that blog says "Good luck!" and you'll need that if you follow his advice...  Follow [this advice](http://askubuntu.com/a/61433/344926) instead.  Much more text to read, but much less chance of failure.  You would not be the first one to brick his system following that blog's advice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers)